# call reselect selectors from redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to call a combined selector from redux-saga by passing video id to selector

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

 const selectVideoStore = state => state.video;

export const selectVideos = createSelector(
  [selectVideoStore],
  video => video.videos
);

export const selectVideosForPreview = ytid =>
  createSelector(
    [selectVideos],
    videos => (videos ? videos[ytid] : null)
  );
```

```
const selectedVideo = yield select(selectVideosForPreview, ytid);
console.log({ selectedVideo });
```

this returns a function in `selectedVideo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `selectVideosForPreview` is not a selector, but a selector factory. So you need to create a selector before passing it into `yield select()`:

```js
const selectedVideo = yield select(selectVideosForPreview(ytid));
```